# C# How to append a character to a listbox DisplayMember?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a listbox with a datatable bound to it. The datatable has two columns, "CMM" and "Location". "CMM" is a one/two digit integer which is used as the DisplayMember for the listbox, and "Location" is a one digit integer, equal to 1 or 2. If the Location column is equal to 2 I would like to add an asterisk to what is displayed in the listbox. I am trying to avoid using drawitem for the listbox.

Comment: Could you bind to a `List<>` and use a property as your displaymember?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [ListBox.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.format(v=vs.110).aspx) event to conditionally change the shown value

EDIT:
Added an example:

At design time, You'll need to create a ListBox control and assign the DisplayMember property to CMM

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    DataTable dt = InitData();
    listBox1.DataSource = dt;
}

private static DataTable InitData() {
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("CMM", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("Location", typeof(int));
    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
    row["CMM"] = 25;
    row["Location"] = 1;
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
    row = dt.NewRow();
    row["CMM"] = 26;
    row["Location"] = 2;
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
    row = dt.NewRow();
    row["CMM"] = 27;
    row["Location"] = 21;
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
    return dt;
}

private void listBox1_Format(object sender, ListControlConvertEventArgs e) {
    //We assigned dataTable with DataRows, but e.ListItem is DataRowView ¿?
    DataRowView rowView = e.ListItem as DataRowView;
    if (rowView != null) {
        e.Value = ((int)rowView.Row["Location"] == 2) ? "*" + rowView.Row["CMM"].ToString() : rowView.Row["CMM"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have the format event in my code, with a foreach loop that cycles through the datatable that is bound to the listbox. It checks if the location at each row is equal to 0, but I'm not sure what comes next. Ex: `if (datatable["Location"].ToString() == "0"){ What goes here? }`

Comment: (Tried to edit my previous comment but it wouldn't let me) I tried putting `if (r["Location"].ToString() == "0"){ lbAllCMM.FormatString = r["Location"].ToString() + "*";}` but this appended the asterisk to every row, not just the rows where the location was equal to 0.

Comment: I have added a working sample of that I think you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was incredibly helpful, and did exactly what I needed to do. Now I just need to learn how it works so I can use it in the future.